# How do I programmatically disable the KDE screen locker?

Tags: command-line, kde, lock-screen

I want to write a shell script that disables the KDE screen locker, sleeps for a while, and then re-enables it.  But I don't know a shell command to control the screen locker.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the same problem and I found your question here but your solution didn't work without modifications in KDE plasma 5.9 so I've continued to search and found your [blog post](http://blog.plover.com/Unix/qdbus-2.html). I've followed your steps and made it work:

```
switch-screenlocker() {
    enabled=""
    case "$1" in
        'on')  enabled='true'  ;;
        'off') enabled='false' ;;
    esac
    if [ -z "${enabled}" -o "$#" -ne 1 ]; then echo "Usage: $0 { on | off }"; return -1; fi
    sed -ni "/Autolock=.*/!{s/\[Daemon]/[Daemon]\nAutolock=${enabled}/;p}" ~/.config/kscreenlockerrc
    qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver configure
}
```

I've changed:

1. config file location `~/.kde/share/config/kscreensaverrc` → `~/.config/kscreenlockerrc`
2. replacement command. I prefer `sed` over `perl` but the significant change is to make it work when there is no `Autolock=true` line in the config. `kcmshell5 screenlocker` removes it since it is assumed by default
3. I wrapped it into function

**UPDATE**:
It appears that 5 minutes timeout is default as well and if the timeout is set to five minutes and locker is enabled, the whole `[Daemon]` section could be missing. I didn't find a way how to handle that situation with `sed` easily but here is an `awk` command which handles that:

```
awk -i inplace 'function p(){set=1;print "[Daemon]\nAutolock='${enabled}'"}
/\[Daemon]/{p();next}
/Autolock.*/{next}
{print}
ENDFILE{if(!set){print "";p()}}' ~/.config/kscreenlockerrc
```

Answer (score 4):

It transpires that the screen locker can be controlled via the D-Bus RPC mechanism.  You can send queries and commands via D-Bus using the `qdbus` command.  The addressable methods are grouped into objects, which belong to services.  Running

```
qdbus
```

prints out a list of services, and you can eyeball this list to find the screen locker service, which is `org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver`.  Then

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver
```

prints out a list of addressable objects in the screen saver service, which includes `/MainApplication`.  (It also includes `/ScreenSaver`, and while this had a number of useful methods, it didn't have what I wanted.)  Then

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /MainApplication
```

prints out a list of callable methods and their argument and return types.  The one you want here is

```
method void org.kde.KApplication.reparseConfiguration()
```

The configuration file itself is in `$HOME/.kde/share/config/kscreensaverrc` and is in a straightforward format.  You can edit this file (programmatically, if desired) and then invoke

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /MainApplication  reparseConfiguration
```

to reconfigure the screen locker with the new configuration.

The complete shell script is:

```
timeout=${1:-3600}
perl -i -lpe 's/^Enabled=.*/Enabled=False/' $HOME/.kde/share/config/kscreensaverrc
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /MainApplication reparseConfiguration
sleep $timeout
perl -i -lpe 's/^Enabled=.*/Enabled=True/' $HOME/.kde/share/config/kscreensaverrc
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /MainApplication reparseConfiguration
```

Frew Schmidt also pointed out that there is often a separate system configuration setting that assigns functions to certain mouse pointer positions, so that it is possible to temporarily disable the screen locker by putting the pointer into the upper right corner, or whatever.  In KDE this is controlled from System Settings → Workspace Behavior → Screen Edges.

Comment: How to do this outside of an X session? When I try running `qdbus` command over SSH (on a host that _does_ have KDE installed), I get `Could not connect to D-Bus server: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`

Comment: The first thing I would try in that case would be setting `DISPLAY` just for the duration of the script:  `DISPLAY=:0 temporarily-disable-screen-saver`.

Answer (score 3):

As Jacob suggests, `kwriteconfig5` can be used as a more elegant way to edit the configuration file. However, some files and functions have been moved/renamed. In KDE 5.27 the correct commands are:

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kscreenlockerrc --group Daemon --key Autolock false
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver configure
```

Replace `false` with `true` to enable the screen locker.

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of KDE you can use kwriteconfig instead of messing around with awk

```
kwriteconfig5 --file kscreensaverrc --group Daemon --key Autolock false
qdbus-qt5 org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /MainApplication reparseConfiguration
```